# Meteor Run mongo-dev-server(project dev local mongo) when using external mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Q.
How to use mongo-dev-server, internal MongoDB in Meteor Project,
during use external MongoDB with ‘export MONGO_URL’?

Explain.
I understand MongoDB must be used fully installed MongoDB version on production mode.
But sometimes I need a temporary DB locally for performance in Scaled out service.

In this case we could set up external local mongodb as well,
but it would be easy to use mongo-dev-server just for temp DB.

#### To be clear

I want to use external MongoDB, set up by export MONGO_URL and default internal MongoDB which is running with meteor command automatically, both.

Because when I set up MONGO_URL when meteor run, the internal mongo db is not running by default.

Comment: what do you mean by mongo-dev-server? I'm not sure I understand which mongodb you are trying to use, the one started by the `meteor` command, or an external one.

Comment: I mean I want to use BOTH it all. Use external one and running mongo-dev-server(the package name default internal mongodb when meteor command runs). I think I should make a question clear a bit more-

Answer (score 0):

You could just set up a mongodb instance that you use for this kind of work. Create a "super user" for this instance that has access to any database. Then use this user in your scratch server, and either give them a new database or use an existing one. A small setup in the first place, and then easy to use from there.

Comment: I think set up another local mongodb would be much easier than your sugession. I don't want to run any other project and make a dependency configure outside of the main project for scale-out or maintain reason.